# How to save the layer as an image in COCOS2D android

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

I want to save all of the work done(every object on the screen) as ONE jpeg image in COCOS2D android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [RenderTexture class](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android/source/browse/trunk/src/org/cocos2d/nodes/RenderTexture.java?r=90) and its saveBuffer method.

Taking a screenshot is the [same process as for the iPhone version (CCRenderTexture)](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/12/how-to-use-ccrendertexture-motion-blur-screenshots-drawing-sketches/).